# Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 generate clone Designer.cs for .resx

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I think its result install update 4

I have **S.resx** and **S.Designer.cs**. After edit in visual designer (in table) **S.resx** - VS generate **S1.Designer.cs** with content of **S.resx** and add **S1.Designer.cs** in solution.

Its not correct. Its duplicate **public class S**. Project in git and i cant replace **S.Designer.cs** with **S1.Designer.cs**

VS must rewrite **S.Designer.cs** with content of **S.resx**.

What can i see and correct?

Answer (score 0):

Solution

1. Delete **S.Designer.cs** and **S1.Designer.cs**.
2. Build (with error)
3. Edit **S.resx**

Now generated only **S.Designer.cs**