# Dataset Designer.cs generate Designer1.cs after taking update from SVN in VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, svn, visual-studio-2013, dataset

I am facing a weird problem after taking update from SVN data-set Designer.cs file generate another file with different name like
test.Designer.cs after update renamed as  test1.Designer.cs . I follow suggestion found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27268416/4336330). but not working again its generate test1.Designer.cs ,please help me to solve this .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Edit the csproj file.
2. Search for `<LastGenOutput>test1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>`.
3. Correct the value so it shows `<LastGenOutput>test.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>`.
4. Delete *test.Designer.cs* and *test1.Designer.cs* from disk.
5. Open the solution again.
6. Right-click on the dataset and click **Run Custom Tool** to regenerate the designer file.

The same problem can also occur with string resource resx files in Visual Studio.

Comment: This works fine but is there any official fix for this bug ? Is this still present in VS2015 ? I'm using VS2013

Comment: @SilentRage47 I'm having the same problem in VS2015 Update 2. Very annoying! Trying to report that now.

Comment: @SilentRage47 This still happens in VS2015 Update 3, as well.

Comment: this fixed my issue, works fine, only i used the designer and pressed control+s to make visual studio save a new designer.cs file and it happened!